# "Abbassare/alzare volume"

Tags: verbs

1)Metti piano/forte il volume.

2)Metti piano/forte la televisione/la radio.

3)Abbassare/alzare/aumentare/diminuire la televisione/la radio.

Ho sentito queste espressioni e, a parte la prima, le altre non mi sembrano del tutto corrette.

Il senso sarebbe:

"Abbassa/aumenta/alza/diminuisci il volume"

Sono utilizzabili oppure sono da ritenere scorrette?

Comment: Mi suonano tutte (a parte “abbassa/aumenta/alza/diminuisci il volume”) piuttosto strane, come se uno straniero traducesse letteralmente espressioni della propria liungua.

Comment: Direi che siano non letteralmente scorrette, ma neanche idiomatiche (vale a dire, nessun madrelingua le userebbe). Ma bisognerebbe che qualcuno scriva una risposta per bene...

Answer (score 2):

Personalmente non ho mai sentito *metti piano il volume* o simili. Si può dire *metti il volume (più) alto* o *metti a volume basso*.

Infatti, normalmente, il volume si *alza* o si *abbassa*. E molto spesso si contrae, nel senso che invece di *alza il volume della radio* si dice *alza la radio* sottintendendo *il volume* (e nessuno va a sollevare l'apparecchio). La versione 3 della domanda letteralmente non avrebbe senso, ma è quello che la gente dice.

Il volume si può anche aumentare o diminuire, anche se a orecchio direi che è molto meno frequente di alzare/abbassare: lo attribuirei a un contesto tecnico, come comandi in una cabina di regia. In questo caso però senza contrazione: *aumenta la televisione* non si sente proprio.

Va notato che *volume* in questa accezione sta per *volume sonoro* ([voce *volume* sul Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/volume), 2d) e *alzare/abbassare* si riferiscono al regolatore di volume sonoro perché si identifica il volume sonoro con la manopola che lo regola.

Comment: Grazie della risposta. Si potrebbe dire "metti basso/alto il volume". Come mi avete fatto notare, però, non si può dire:  A)"metti piano la tv/radio" o B)"metti piano il volume", ma " metti basso il volume". Se invece sostituissimo "piano" col suo contrario "forte" nelle due frasi ( A e B) sarebbe da ritenere corretto e/o più naturale/idiomatico?

Comment: @Maxim “Metti più alta la TV” non mi suona affatto strano e non mi verrebbe in mente di sollevarla, ma solo di agire sul volume. “Metti piano la TV” può anche andare, perché no?

Answer (score 0):

Come notato nei commenti, la 1 e la 2 sono, perlomeno, poco o niente idiomatiche. Si può anche aggiungere che "metti piano" può significare "metti dolcemente", come in "fa' piano" o "mettilo giù piano".

Detto questo, personalmente le prime due non le ritengo esattamente scorrette, potrebbero esserci contesti in cui non suonano male; certamente però è meglio evitarle. Forse un poco meglio sarebbe qualcosa come "metti basso il volume".